# Confusion on a directional derivative expression

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying "A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds" and came across a confusing part on intro to directional derivatives. First the definition

> The directional derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction of the unit vector $u=[a,b]^T$ is
>   $$D_uf(x_0,y_0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ta,y_0+tb)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$$
>   if this limit exists

This definition makes sense. But then there's:

> To remind ourselves of some other equivalent notations, notice that if we let $p=(x_0,y_0)$ then we can also write
>   $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ta,y_0+tb)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(f(p+tu)\bigg)\bigg|_{t=0}$$

I don't understand how the expression on the right came about. The expression on the left indicates the incremental change in $f$ as we vary the vector $x$ from its initial value $[x_0,y_0]^T$, which is why it makes sense. I thought maybe we could write $g(t)=f(x_0+ta,y_0+tb)$, and so its derivative would be

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ta+ha,y_0+tb+hb)-f(x_0+ta,y_0+tb)}{h}$$

which is the same as the first $D_u$ expression **when** we put $t=0$. But I'm still not 100% certain since this seems like a very roundabout way of getting the same thing. Why even go through so much trouble if we have a perfectly good definition in the first place? Apologies if this is a naive question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start on the other side:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( f(p+tu) \bigg)\bigg|_{t=0} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(p+(0+h)u)-f(p+(0)u)}{h}. $$
Now change the limit variable to $t$.

**Addendum.** This reworking of the directional derivative is useful because it makes it clear that it coincides with the standard one-dimensional derivative of the *restriction* of $f$ to the line defined the point $p$ and the vector $u$. This links them to the usual intuition for partial derivatives (directional derivatives where said line is either horizontal or vertical) and allows us to think of subtleties such as "if all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at a point, does the differential of $f$ necessarily exist?" in a more geometrical sense. (Spoiler: it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function of a single variable $t$ as
$$g(t):=f(x_0+at, y_0+bt)$$
You can see $g$ as a composite of $f$ with the single variable function
$$t\longmapsto (x_0+at, y_0+bt)$$
Then by definition of the derivative for functions of a single variable, we have
$$g'(t)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}$$
and the derivative at $t=0$ is given by
$$g'(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$$
If we now substitute in for $g(t)$, we get
$$g'(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ah, y_0+bh)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$
which is precisely the directional derivative of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$, along the direction given by $(a,b)$.